# Why is this edit shown as just me?

Tags: support, bug, editing, suggested-edits, edit-history

I made [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2085544/2) edit, and it was approved, however the final change included edits I didn't make

The edits I didn't make were the removing of a tag and noise at the end of the post. I recognize I probably should've removed the noise, but I didn't really think of it at the time.

The true problem however, is that edits I didn't make are made, and instead of saying someone "edited and approved", it just says it I made the edit, and it was approved.

Comment: Do you definitely recall  that the phrase you do not recall  removing was even in the source you edited? I ask since an explanation for what happened could be you *started* editing based on version of this question that was *not identical* to the one in place when you *submitted* the edit. The  "difference" is then your actual changes plus the changes to the "base" that happened while you edited. This seems plausible given the proximity of original post and your edit and the  fact that the phrase is marked up with "EDIT" so in all likely hood was added by OP only somewhat after submitting.

Comment: @quid, I'm positive, but that seems like a perfectly plausible and reasonable explanation.